# Quantifying physical intuition about heat and motion

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

Assume that we are in deep space. There are two objects Orange and Blue. Initially, Orange is at a temperature of 200K and Blue is at 1000K. Consider the following scenarios. For now assume that there are no molecular forces or gravitational attraction between the objects. No radiation.

**Case 1**

Initial state

[image]

Now, initially they are in contact. Hence Blue transfers small amount of energy to Orange. By this we mean, the molecules at the interface exchange energy. Orange experiences a slight leftward force (because of heat) due to Blue and hence moves to left. Blue moves to right as a result. Then after some time, they appear to be

[image]
But after a long time, since both of them have velocity away from each other, they become infinitely far apart (I know that its possible that $v<v_{esc}$, but ignore gravity for now).

**Case 2**

Initial State

[image]

Here the one-dimensional object is a very thin metallic wire. By similar reasoning we can predict that after some time the system appears to be like

[image]

But due to the initial velocities, the system follows a periodic motion (orange and blue get as far as the length of the wire which is taut and then to coming in contact).

**0) Are these correct?**

**1) How can we quantify the results?**

**2) How could have people in the 19th century (no knowledge of atoms and molecules) predicted the results?**

**3) How do the answers change when we add physical complications?**

Comment: I don't think your 1st conclusion holds in general. I think the problem is that you have some picture "without molecular forces", but without some sort of force there is no way to transfer heat. How are you picturing heat transfer happening here?

Comment: @By Symmetry I meant there are no attractive forces. When I think about heat, I imagine molecules vibrating and rotating about centre of mass. So when a highly vibrating molecules are in the neighborhood of a lesser vibrating molecules, the first set tries to increase the vibration of the slower ones. Overall, I imagine some kind of resonance when they are in thermal equilibrium. Is my intuition wrong here?

Comment: I mean if all the forces in your model are repulsive then things will repel each other, but this is not very surprising and doesn't have anything to do with heat. Resonance is not the right way to think about thermal equilibrium. Atoms are always moving. If they all move in the same direction this becomes something we can microscopically observe. If they are moving more or less at random this is what we observe as thermal energy.

Comment: As atoms move, they exchange energy through inter-molecular forces. If the average of the random thermal motion of atoms results in a net transfer of energy over large distances this is what we observe as heat. Thermal equilibrium is a state with no heat flow, i.e. on average there is not net flow of thermal energy. This does not depend in any way on the nature of the inter-molecular forces, only that they exist. Heat can be exchanged through attractive forces just as well as repulsive ones.

Comment: Hmm..makes sense. So, in this problem, the attractive/repulsive forces themselves cause heat and increase the temperature of Blue and possibly change the position of CoM. But, will the momentum transfer due to repulsive forces be enough to overcome the attractive forces? Can we even predict the results given the materials? Sorry for asking too many questions....

Comment: @BySymmetry given the materials and the initial macroscopic conditions...

Comment: Working out whether the net force is attractive or repulsive boils down to calculating the electronic structure of the materials at the interface. This is a very large field but the short answer is we probably can but it requires a computer. Once we have done that working out the expected momentum transfer in the repulsive case should be doable with kinetic theory, although the answer may be more or less complicated depending on how accurate an answer you want.

Comment: I should probably add that the expected momentum transfer will depend a lot on how your original setup was being held together before release